# AJAX call from TXT :How to "convert" text from html to ejs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, xmlhttprequest, ejs

I have created a web page where when you click a button, it "reads" a TXT file and adds its text to the page.

The web page is an EJS page.

I'm trying to pass some EJS code through the TXT file but it does not work because the page does not render the EJS code.

```
<div style="text-align:center" id="mostraid">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="MostraID('../public/ajaxtext.txt',CB)" >MOSTRA ID</button>
</div>
<script>
function MostraID(url, cFunction) {
    var xhttp;
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            cFunction(this);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
function CB(xhttp) {
    document.getElementById("mostraid").innerHTML =
        xhttp.responseText;
}
</script>
```

The ajaxtext.txt file contains:
    Your user ID is <%=user.id%>

The AJAX call works fine, but the web page displays "Your user ID is <%=user.id%>" instead of "Your user ID is 834948394583(example)"

Is there some way to convert the text in the txt file to EJS?
This web page is included in an Express project, so I can add some server side code if needed.

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for my bad english!

EDIT: Semplified function without Callback

```
<div style="text-align:center" id="mostraid">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" onclick="MostraID()" >MOSTRA ID</button>
</div>
<script>
function MostraID() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("mostraid").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "../public/ajaxtext.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Comment: have you tried simplifying your 2 functions into one function?

Comment: I can do that, but probably the outcome won't change

Comment: Perhaps, but simplifying code where possible , IMHO, is always good.

Comment: Absolutely, I'll update it when I come back from work.